# How can I pass the table id to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using tabs and have 3 tables.  One in each tab.  I want to pass the table id to my javascript to perform adds and deletes to the table rows.  Table ids are
"modexcl1"
"modexcl2"
"modexcl3"
when I click the "Add" button the dialog window appears and I can add text.  However when I click "Create Record"  it does not add the record and tells me the table id is "undefined"

I tried the code below  however the alert says undefined:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
       var dialog, form;
       var tabId = $(table).attr('id');
       alert (Table ID: "+ tabId); 
       function addModule() {
          var valid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
     
          //valid = checkRegexp( port, /^([0-9])+$/, "Port field only allow : 0-9" );
          //alert("Valid: " + valid);
          if ( valid ) {
              //alert("Name: " + mod.val());
              table1.row.add( {
                      "Module":   mod.val(),
              } ).draw();
              dialog.dialog( "close" );
          }
          return valid;
        }
    
    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 250,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create Record": addModule1, Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });
    
    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addModule();
    });
    
    $( "#create-record" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
           
    // Delete a record
    $('#modexcl1 tbody').on('click', 'tr .fa-trash', function () {
      var row = table1.row( this.closest('tr') );
      ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");
      if (ans) {
         table1.row( row ).remove().draw();
      }
    } );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on the Module Type to view the exclude list:</p>
    
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="modExcl(event, 'Module')">Module</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="modExcl(event, 'Switch')">Switch</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Module" class="tabcontent">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="dt">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table').DataTable( {
             "autoWidth": true,
             "scrollY": "400px",
             "scrollX": true,
             "dom": '<lf<t>Bip>',
             "lengthMenu": [[20,30,50,-1], [20,30,50,"All"]],
             "columns": [
                { data: "Module" },
                {
                    data: null,
                    id: "delete",
                    defaultContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash"/>',
                    orderable: false
                }
             ],
             "buttons": [
                 'csv'
             ] } );
      } );
    </script>
    <script src="/xxx/js/modexcl1.js"></script>
      <h3>Exclude List for Module</h3>
      <table id="modexcl1" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Module</th>
                   <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>C3KX-NM-10G</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>IE-2000-16PTC-G-E</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
        <form action="">
         <div align="center">
           <input type="button" id="create-record1" value="Add" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"></input>
           <input type="button" id="saveTab1" value="Save" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"></input>
         </div>
        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Switch" class="tabcontent">
    <script src="/Billing/js/modexcl2.js"></script>
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Exclude List for Switch</h3>
        <table id="modexcl2" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Module</th>
                   <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>C4KX-NM-8</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C9200-24P</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
        <form action="">
         <div align="center">
           <input type="button" id="create-record1" value="Add" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"></input>
           <input type="button" id="saveTab1" value="Save" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"></input>
         </div>
        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I made a runnable snippet from your code. Your code has multiple syntax errors. Please correct those first so that we can get to the core issue. I am not sure if your source code shares these same syntax errors so I left them in.

Comment: no I didn't add all the code just some snippets.  do you want me to add the rest?

Comment: you can check it out here: http://live.datatables.net/badekace/2/edit

Comment: Yes, if you can then you will increase the chances of solving your issue

Comment: Well, I've tried adding the rest of your code in but unfortunately it is 4k characters too long for SO to allow. If you can isolate the issue into a minimal reproducible example then that would be good.

Comment: can you go to this URL and try?  http://live.datatables.net/badekace/2/edit

Comment: I trimmed it down quite a bit